# PhoneGap: variable scope

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to write a function that returns an object representing the position of the device: I have tried:

```
  function getDevicePosition () {
    var positionObject;
    if (isDeviceReady) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            positionObject = position;
            console.log('location updated');
            console.log(positionObject.coords.longitude);//1. works
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('Failed to get device position' + err);
            return null;
        });

    } else {
        warnUser();
        return null;
    }
    console.log(positionObject.coords.longitude);//2. doesnt work as positionObject is null.
    return positionObject;
}
```

Notice that I have added comments marking statement 1 and statement 2. If I initialized position object in statement 1. Why is it undefined in statement 2?

Comment: if thats the case, how do I return position object from inside the callback such that it gets returned out of the getDevicePosition() function.

Comment: You can't. Do what you need to do inside the callback. You could make your `getDevicePosition` function accept a callback function of it's own, and then call that from the `getCurrentPosition` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation#Getting_the_current_position) is an *asynchronous* method. The line marked as `2` will run before the callback function gets a chance to execute, so `positionObject` will still be `undefined`.

You need to move all code that depends on `positionObject` inside the callback to `getCurrentPosition`.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, so the execution of the rest of the function does not wait until it is finished.

So your function is at execution basically reduced to this:

```
function getDevicePosition () {
    var positionObject;
    if (isDeviceReady) {
        // trigger some asynch function ...
    } else {
        warnUser();
        return null;
    }
    console.log(positionObject.coords.longitude);
    return positionObject;
}
```

From this code it should be pretty obvious, that at the point, your code reaches the `console.log()` your positionObject is not set, thus resulting in the error.

**EDIT**

With respect to your comment. The general design principle for such tasks is as follows:

```
// original function (triggered by a button or whatever)
function trigger() {
  // do some calculations before

  // trigger the position-retrival
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    // get the position
    // ...

    // call the handling function
    doStuff( position );
  });
}

// the function to do stuff based on the position
function doStuff( position ) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: if thats the case, how do I return position object from inside the callback such that it gets returned out of the getDevicePosition() function.

Comment: @user1476075 You basically can't. The design principle here is to trigger a function from inside the callback, which handles all dependent code.